# What is the Pointer Design Pattern (PDP) for function pointers in Python?

Tags: python, pointers, design-patterns, polymorphism, function-pointers

How can I practice polymorphism in Python?

Let's assume a very simplified version of option pricing algorithm, which only needs three inputs (option_type, spot_price and strike_price) to determine the intrinsic value of our option. Please have a look at the example code below.

Although, I have used the inheritance to make my code more manageable, the implementation of method "calculate_option_price" is not stable. That is due to the fact that a new elif should be added for each new option_type in the future. In other words, by adding more elif for each new option_type in the future, the implementation size may grow undesirably and becomes more prone to mistake during future developments. How can I solve that issue in Python by replicating the behaviour of function pointers in C++ & C#?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import attr


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class Option(ABC):
    strike_price:float

    @abstractmethod
    def price(self, spot_price: float):
        raise NotImplementedError("This method must be implemented in the subclasses.")

class Call(Option):
    def price(self,spot_price: float) -> float:
        return spot_price - self.strike_price

class Put(Option):
    def price(self,spot_price: float) -> float:
        return self.strike_price - spot_price


def calculate_option_price(option_type:str, spot_price:float, strike_price:float) -> float:
     if option_type == "CALL":
         return Call(strike_price=strike_price).price(spot_price=spot_price)
     elif option_type == "PUT":
         return Put(strike_price=strike_price).price(spot_price=spot_price)

option_price = calculate_option_price(option_type="CALL", spot_price=120, strike_price=80)

print(f"option price is {option_price}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pointer Design Pattern (PDP) enables you to practice Polymorphism in Python and partially replicate the behaviour of function pointers similar to the way they work in C++ & C#. In contrast to C++, you don't need to be worried about classic drawbacks of pointers such as memory leakage if you use the PDP in Python.

The Pointer Design Pattern (PDP) uses an enum object to map all the potential option types to its own corresponding object. More importantly, that stables the implementation of "calculate_option_price" method for future development, as it does not need to be modified if a new option type is added in the future. Please have a look at the following example:

```
from enum import Enum, unique
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import attr


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class Option(ABC):
    strike_price:float

    @abstractmethod
    def price(self, spot_price: float):
        raise NotImplementedError("This method must be overrode in the subclasses.")

class Call(Option):
    def price(self,spot_price: float) -> float:
        return spot_price - self.strike_price

class Put(Option):
    def price(self,spot_price: float) -> float:
        return self.strike_price - spot_price

@unique
class OptionType(Enum):
    PUT=Put
    CALL=Call


def calculate_option_price(option_type:str, spot_price:float, strike_price:float) -> float:
    pointer = OptionType[option_type].value
    return pointer(strike_price=strike_price).price(spot_price=spot_price)

option_price = calculate_option_price(option_type="CALL", spot_price=120, strike_price=80)

print(f"option price is {option_price}.")
```